# Issue running Node Express server and Angular App on NGINX the same server

Tags: angular, express, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm in the process of deploying my first angular app to production, but I can't get my NGINX server to hit my endpoints on Express.

My setup(all running on the same EC2 instance):

1. node express server successfully running over port: 3000 for the API (I can hit the endpoints VIA browser)
2. NGINX server successfully hosting my Angular App over port: 81.

In my angular app, I used an environments.prod.ts file to declare the serverUrl for the http requests.

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  serverUrl: 'localhost:3000'
};
```

This is where I'm fairly certain where my issue is. What should my server URL be?

This is the specific error I get when I try and make the http req via the app:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzZdD.png)

Edit:
I fixed my environments file to include the "http://", but now I get this error. To be honest, I'm not 100% sure how CORS works. I'm very very new to all of this.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/openapp/2019-12-01. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing Cors configuration.
Here are mine that work in production environment =>

```
import cors from 'cors';
const options: cors.CorsOptions = corsOptions: {
  allowedHeaders: ['Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'Accept', 'X-Access-Token'],
  credentials: 'true',
  methods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
  origin: '*',
  preflightContinue: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204
},
```

Use them for your router on options requests:

```
router.options('*', cors(options))
```

Please be careful with the origin '*'. Make sure to put your domain name there if you won't wanna make your api open to the whole web through ajax.

One more thing, If I may suggest something, you don't have to expose your 3000 port, just go through nginx on port 80, that way you can list your api baseUrl as /api and that's it.

This is how i did it personaly =>
For the nginx part, here is the Express configuration:

```
upstream node_upstream {
        server      127.0.0.1:3000;
        keepalive   64;
}

...
server {
    location /api {
        ...

        client_max_body_size        3M;
        client_body_buffer_size     1M;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_max_temp_file_size    0;
        proxy_pass              http://node_upstream;
        proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
        proxy_connect_timeout   120;
        proxy_read_timeout      120;
        proxy_send_timeout      120;
        proxy_redirect          off;
    }

}
```